# Use Schema inside another Schema not working. Error: CastError: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, schema, backend, mongoose-schema

What I'm trying to achieve: Use one Schema (Ingredient Schema) inside another one (Recipe Schema). My goal is that in the Recipe Schema, my ingredients key to be an array of my Ingredient Schema. Not sure why it's not working or what I am doing wrong. If you guys have any idea I would really appreciate it. Please see below my code. Thanks!

Error I get, when I call my seeds.js:

```
Error: Recipe validation failed: ingredients.0: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "[{"ingName":"tomato","ingQty":2,"ingQtyUnit":"piece","ingImageUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Tomato_je.jpg"},{"ingName":"onion","ingQty":1,"ingQtyUnit":"piece","ingImageUrl":"https://www.seeds-gallery.shop/9430-large_default/onion-seeds-dutch-yellow.jpg"}]" (type string) at path "ingredients.0

'ingredients.0': CastError: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "[{"ingName":"tomato","ingQty":2,"ingQtyUnit":"piece","ingImageUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Tomato_je.jpg"},{"ingName":"onion","ingQty":1,"ingQtyUnit":"piece","ingImageUrl":"https://www.seeds-gallery.shop/9430-large_default/onion-seeds-dutch-yellow.jpg"}]" (type string) at path "ingredients.0"

      stringValue: '"[{"ingName":"tomato","ingQty":2,"ingQtyUnit":"piece","ingImageUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Tomato_je.jpg"}]"',
      messageFormat: undefined,
      kind: '[ObjectId]',
      value: '[{"ingName":"tomato","ingQty":2,"ingQtyUnit":"piece","ingImageUrl":"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Tomato_je.jpg"}]',
      path: 'ingredients.0',
      reason: [CastError],
      valueType: 'string'
    }
  },
  _message: 'Recipe validation failed'
```

How I was trying to do it:

Recipe Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const recipeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    calories: {
        type: Number, 
        required: false,
    }, 
    duration: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
    },
    ingredients:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
        ref: "Ingredient"
    }]
})

const Recipe = mongoose.model('Recipe', recipeSchema);

module.exports = Recipe;
```

Ingredient Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ingredientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ingName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    ingQty: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    ingQtyUnit: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    ingImageUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
})

const Ingredient = mongoose.model('Ingredient', ingredientSchema);

module.exports = Ingredient;
```

seeds.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Recipe = require('./models/recipe');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/foodApp', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Mongo Connection open")
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("No, Mongo -> Connection Error " + error)
    })

const seedRecipes = [
    {
        title: "Spring vegetable pie",
        imageUrl: "https://recipes.lidl.co.uk/var/site/storage/images/1/9/4/3/243491-2-eng-GB/Spring-vegetable-pie.jpg",
        calories: 300,
        duration: 120,
        ingredients:[
            {
            ingName: "tomato",
            ingQty: 2,
            ingQtyUnit: "piece",
            ingImageUrl:"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Tomato_je.jpg" 
        },
        {
            ingName: "onion",
            ingQty: 1,
            ingQtyUnit: "piece",
            ingImageUrl:"https://www.seeds-gallery.shop/9430-large_default/onion-seeds-dutch-yellow.jpg" 
        },
      ]
    },
]

Recipe.insertMany(seedRecipes)
.then(response => {
    console.log(response)
})
.catch( error => {
    console.log(error)
});
```

Comment: At the moment I can only think of doing with multiple steps. I'm not sure if insertMany can handle that without additional implementation.

Comment: Thank you @GytisTG for replying! What are you exactly referring to when saying multiple steps? Sorry if this might sound stupid, just started learning coding and precisely backend coding. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Yours is even shorter than I originally thought :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is looking for an answer, this is what I've done. I created a new `seeds` folder with 2 files `index.js` `seeds.js`.

In my `seeds.js` I added my data recipes objects and exported it so I can use it somewhere else.

```
module.exports = [
    {
        title: "Mushroom and courgette fritter burgers",
        imageUrl: "https://recipes.lidl.co.uk/var/site/storage/images/2/5/4/2/252452-2-eng-GB/Mushroom-and-courgette-fritter-burgers.jpg",
        calories: 250,
        duration: 30,
        ingredients: [
            {
                ingName: "mushrooms",
                ingQty: 200,
                ingQtyUnit: "grams",
                ingImageUrl:"https://snaped.fns.usda.gov/sites/default/files/styles/crop_ratio_7_5/public/seasonal-produce/2018-05/mushrooms.jpg?h=b754914e&itok=Kldbq8Du" 
            },
            {
                ingName: "zucchini",
                ingQty: 2,
                ingQtyUnit: "piece",
                ingImageUrl:"https://healme.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/zucchini-2-1200.jpg" 
            }
        ]
    },    
]
```

Then, in my `index.js` from seeds folder

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Recipe = require('../models/recipe');
const Ingredient = require ('../models/ingredient')
const recipes = require('../seeds/seeds')

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/foodApp', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => {
        console.log("Mongo Connection open from seeds")
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log("No, Mongo -> Connection Error " + error)
    })

const seedDB = async () => {
    await Recipe.deleteMany({});
    let title;
    let imageUrl;
    let calories;
    let duration;
    let ingredients;
    for (let i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++) {
        title = recipes[i].title;
        imageUrl = recipes[i].imageUrl;
        calories = recipes[i].calories;
        duration = recipes[i].duration;
        ingredients = recipes[i].ingredients;
        for (let ing of ingredients) {
            ingredients = ing;
        }
    const newRecipe = new Recipe ({
        title: title,
        imageUrl: imageUrl,
        calories: calories,
        duration: duration,
        ingredients: new Ingredient({
            ingName: ingredients.ingName,
            ingQty: ingredients.ingQty,
            ingQtyUnit: ingredients.ingQtyUnit,
            ingImageUrl:ingredients.ingImageUrl,
        })
    })
        await newRecipe.save();
    }
}

seedDB();
```

Recipe Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const recipeSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    calories: {
        type: Number, 
        required: false,
    }, 
    duration: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 0,
    },
    ingredients: {
        _id: {
          type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
          ref:"Ingredient"
        }, 
        ingName: String,
        ingQty: Number, 
        ingQtyUnit: String,
        ingImageUrl: String,
    },
})

const Recipe = mongoose.model('Recipe', recipeSchema);

module.exports = Recipe;
```

Ingredient Schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ingredientSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    ingName: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    ingQty: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    ingQtyUnit: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    ingImageUrl: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
})

const Ingredient = mongoose.model('Ingredient', ingredientSchema);

module.exports = Ingredient;
```